# Can Xbox One join Minecraft Pocket edition server over WiFi LAN?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-legacy-console

Or one has to pay for Realm thingy? There were some updates lately so things may have improved with platform compatibility.

I've bought Xbox360 before, and now it seems I need to pay 20 euro to get Xbox One version, but it does not make much sense if I cannot play with PE over LAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, now reading xbox help http://support.xbox.com/en-US/legacy-devices/windows-phone-8/minecraft-pocket-edition-on-mobile-devices-help and it says

> Note Minecraft: Xbox 360 Edition can only be played with other Xbox 360 consoles on Xbox Live, and the Xbox One edition can only be played online with other Xbox One consoles. There is no cross-platform play between the Xbox console versions and any other version of Minecraft.

Quite disappointing...

Answer (score 1):

Minecraft: Pocket Edition is a completely different version of Minecraft compared to the Console Editions and the Java editions. As such, cross-play is not possible between Pocket Edition and the Xbox One edition.